# Macbook Pro gets warm while running Android virtual device

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am trying to develop a Flutter application and for that purpose I created an Android Virutal Device. 
However, when I run the app, macbook gets really warm.

Does this happen to anyone of you? What could be the problem?

Comment: This happens to me as well.  What's especially disconcerting is that the computer stays hot even when asleep if the emulator is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your fans shut off soon after you close the application, there is no problem. When your computer is working hard it will turn on the fans to cool it self off. It would be more concerning if the fans didn't turn on as that could result in permanent damage.

Virtual machine will often work a computer because its running two virtual devices on one physical device.

Just know your fans are

1. Keeping your mac's internals safe
2. Allowing your Mac to perform at its best
3. Not an indication of a problem (unless they are on all the time)